# Air Pressure in a Mine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, atmospheric-science, fluid-statics

In Sunday's "60 Minutes" TV program the correspondent descended into a gold mine said to be 2 miles (3 km) deep.  What equation describes the air pressure relative to sea level atmospheric pressure?

Comment: [Pressure and density of air in mines](http://nopr.niscair.res.in/bitstream/123456789/2506/1/IJRSP%2037%281%29%2064-67.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Barometric formula is the equation which can estimate the pressure at different heights:

$$
p=p_0\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{mgh}{k_BT}\right)
$$

The $p_0$ is the reference pressure, $T$ is the temperature in K, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, and $h$ is the height.

Comment: Kiitos (thanks) @kalle for the edit of the equation.

Comment: This equation suppose constant temperature. It is not the case in a deep mine ?

Comment: There are few assumptions. For instanec, this equation gives the pressure of a point with a temperature in equilibrium.

Comment: And $m$ is what? Probably the mass of a single air molecule.

Comment: Indeed, formula is a bit messed-up, it should [sound like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) : $$ P=P_{0}e^{-Mgz/R^{*}T} $$ where $M$ is an air molar mass and $R^{*}$ is a gas constant.